# Attempting to capture multiple groups but only the last group is captured

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex to help to convert the following string into a Dictionary:

```
{TheKey|TheValue}{AnotherKey|AnotherValue}
```

Like such:

```
["TheKey"] = "TheValue"
["AnotherKey"] = "AnotherValue"
```

To parse the string for the dictionary, I am using the regex expression:

```
 ^(\{(.+?)\|(.+?)\})*?$
```

But it will only capture the last group of {AnotherKey|AnotherValue}.

How do I get it to capture all of the groups?

I am using C#.

Alternatively, is there a more straightforward way to approach this rather than using Regex?

Code (Properties["PromptedValues"] contains the string to be parsed):

```
var regex = Regex.Matches(Properties["PromptedValues"], @"^(\{(.+?)\|(.+?)\})*?$");

foreach(Match match in regex) {

    if(match.Groups.Count == 4) {

        var key = match.Groups[2].Value.ToLower();
        var value = match.Groups[3].Value;

        values.Add(key, new StringPromptedFieldHandler(key, value));
     }

}
```

This is coded to work for the single value, I would be looking to update it once I can get it to capture multiple values.

Comment: If you need to do it with a regex, you need `@"{(.+?)\|(.+?)}"`.

Comment: then show your c# code cos it s hould do them if you set them right

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The `@` goes inside `""`?

Comment: How do you call this regex? `.Matches` returns all matches while `.Match` returns just one match. Anyway, you request a match against an entire line

Comment: Code Pasted in Edit above

Comment: @fabiosa you can name the fields and retrieve them by name, rather than using indexes

Comment: No need for a regex, use `var the_result = str_input.Split(new[] { "{", "}" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToDictionary(m => m.Split('|')[0],  m => m.Split('|')[1]);`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no need for splitting when you have a regex. Have you considered how many temporary strings are generated by splitting? How much CPU load this generates? You can get 10x faster performance when parsing a log file simply by using a regex instead of splitting.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I suggest you try splitting vs a regex on a large file with Benchmark.net and check allocations and CPU. Even the difference in RAM usage can be shocking, with splitting eating up hundreds of megabytes, when a regex remains in the low tens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $ says that: The match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the end of the line or string.

The ^ says that: The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.

Read this for more regex syntax: [msdn RegEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Once you remove the ^ and $ your regex will match all of the sets You should read: [Match.Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) and get something like the following:

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string pattern = @"\{(.+?)\|(.+?)\}";
      string input = "{TheKey|TheValue}{AnotherKey|AnotherValue}";
      MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

      foreach (Match match in matches)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("The Key: {0}", match.Groups[1].Value);
         Console.WriteLine("The Value: {0}", match.Groups[2].Value);
         Console.WriteLine();
      }
      Console.WriteLine();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was over complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex tries to match against the entire line. You can get individual pairs if you *don't* use anchors:

```
var input = Regex.Matches("{TheKey|TheValue}{AnotherKey|AnotherValue}");    
var matches=Regex.Matches(input,@"(\{(.+?)\|(.+?)\})");
Debug.Assert(matches.Count == 2);
```

It's better to name the fields though:

```
var matches=Regex.Matches(input,@"\{(?<key>.+?)\|(?<value>.+?)\}");
```

This allows you to access the fields by name, and even use LINQ:

```
var pairs= from match in matches.Cast<Match>()
           select new {
                          key=match.Groups["key"].Value,
                          value=match.Groups["value"].Value
                      };
```

Comment: I did not know you could name the fields that is a nice feature.

Comment: @JaredStroeb once you start working with Splunk, you discover a lot of interesting Regex features

Comment: Definitely going to use named groupings next time I am doing complected regex.  I was setting my indexes to variables something like: `int KEY = 1;  match.Groups[KEY].Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the `Captures` property of your groups to get all of the times they matched.

```
if (regex.Success)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < regex.Groups[1].Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        var key = regex.Groups[2].Captures[i].Value.ToLower();
        var value = regex.Groups[3].Captures[i].Value;
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of still checking that *your entire string was made up of matches*. Solutions suggesting you remove the anchors will find things that look like matches in a longer string, but will not fail for you if anything was malformed.